# Why can't I take pictures?

Tags: camera, insufficient-memory, storage

Every time I go into my camera it says "your storage is full" I've deleted apps I've deleted pictures and I've cleared data and cleared cache and everything so why can't I take pictures it and it still says storage full?

Comment: Is this a camera on a phone?

Comment: Have you set your camera location to a sd card?

Comment: What type of device are you using? How much storage do you think you have? Do you have an external memory card in the device?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Please take a backup of your phone. Perform a factory data reset.

Set your default location of your camera storage to SD card.